# Headphone jack outputting sound but not receiving input Lenovo Ideapad S145

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, headphone-jack

For some reason my headphone jack mysteriously stopped receiving input. If I plug a headphone with a mic in I can hear but cannot talk with the mic. At first I thought the headphone was to blame and switched headphones but the new ones didn't work either. They both had microphones but neither mics worked. I re-installed all the audio drivers with no avail.

I suspect that the headphone jack has malfunctioned as any headphone I plug in shows roughly the same symptoms. The headphones I tested were:

- Turtle Beach Headphones (1 Ear)
- JBL ANC Headphone

Every single app I try to use with the mic says they're receiving no input when I am speaking.

Comment: The headphone jack of a laptop isn’t the same as the one in your smartphone, this is a common misconception where people think that they are similar. Usually the headphone jacks in laptop are only supposed to output audio and not take input even if you have the supported hardware.

Comment: Try using a Bluetooth headset with inbuilt microphone, it should solve your problem.

Comment: If you check whether your laptop has the headphone jack which supports audio input, go to your audio settings in windows and set up your mic.

Comment: @Valay_17 The audio setup seems to be fine with it asking me to read a sentence somewhat like "Peter likes to use his computer..." and then presenting me with 2 buttons - close the troubleshooter and give feedback to the troubleshooter.

Comment: Mind sharing the screenshot? You can share it in the comments section by converting it to an imgur link.

Comment: Here: https://ibb.co/dMxscP4 - the part where it says "Peter uses his computer..." I couldn't use Imgur - sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Did you try saying those words and did it recognize your voice?

Comment: Yes, it did recognise my voice (the green bar went up) but every other app I use won't pick up my voice.

Comment: Go to settings and under the privacy section go to microphone and select everything to on and try if those applications are able to take the input.

Comment: @Valay_17 The issue seems to have fixed it's self when I set up the mic. Maybe its to do with the setup issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great, enjoy interacting with others.